# using sudo with piped command on Ubuntu server

Tags: backup, sudo, tar, pipe

If I need to use the following backup command on an Ubuntu server with sudo, how do I do so? Do I need sudo at two places?

```
tar cf - directory | 7za a -si directory.tar.7z
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the sudo manual. You can use a single sudo command doing:

```
sudo sh -c 'tar cf - directory | 7za a -si directory.tar.7z'
```